# How do I run Minecraft-Console-Client on Ubuntu?

Tags: compiling, git, mono, github, c#

I want to install the GitHub app found [here](https://github.com/ORelio/Minecraft-Console-Client).
The problem is that according to the README.txt file in the [config](https://github.com/ORelio/Minecraft-Console-Client/MinecraftClient/config) folder, I need to run

```
mono MinecraftClient.exe
```

but that command only returns

> Cannot open assembly 'MinecraftClient'.exe' : no such file or directory

I have no idea how to do this since I'm not at all good at programming. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
**The program is written in C#**

*I'm using a terminal only version of Ubuntu so there's no desktop.*

Comment: Are you running the command in a directory that contains MinecraftClient.exe?

Comment: There isn't a MinecraftClient.exe anywhere in the program, so I don't know what the creator meant with that command. As far as I know, I'm supposed to compile(?) the files inside the config folder or run the config folder as an .exe. Not sure though, since again, I have zero programming knowledge

Comment: As stated in the readme, you should download MinecraftClient.exe from: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/ORelio/minecraft-console-client/build/artifacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [readme](https://github.com/ORelio/Minecraft-Console-Client) states, you don't have to build the project from source - just grab the latest development build (`MinecraftClient.exe`) from:

https://ci.appveyor.com/project/ORelio/minecraft-console-client/build/artifacts

Here's a summary of required steps on Ubuntu:

1. Install Mono: `sudo apt-get install mono-runtime libmono-reflection-cil`
2. Download `MinecraftClient.exe` from the above link
3. Run `mono MinecraftClient.exe`.